# Select from sql in vb and display in aspx page

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, vb.net

Just wanna select a word from database and display in aspx page

Backend

```
Using da As New SqlDataAdapter
        con.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT value_en as value FROM tbl_language WHERE element_id = 'a1';"
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        Dim WordValue As String = dt.Rows(0).Item(0)
End Using
```

in aspx page

```
<%=WordValue%>
```

whats wrong here?

Comment: Try `<%# Eval("WordValue")%>`

Answer (score 0):

Assign Connection to the command object and also convert item(0) into string

```
Using da As New SqlDataAdapter
        con.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT value_en as value FROM tbl_language WHERE element_id = 'a1';"
        cmd.Connection =con
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        Dim WordValue As String = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows(0).Item(0))
End Using
```

or

```
Using da As New SqlDataAdapter( "SELECT value_en as value FROM tbl_language WHERE element_id = 'a1';",con)
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)
            Dim WordValue As String = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows(0).Item(0))
    End Using
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on what changes you have made so others can benefit from it

Comment: @Izzy i add this `cmd.Connection =con ` and this
 `Dim WordValue As String = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows(0).Item(0))`